# Change the HOME of a user during a graphical session

Tags: linux, users, session

The other day I had the idea to create display manager independent guest session.

My basic idea was to change the login shell to a custom program that creates a temporary home on the fly (f.e. `/tmp/guest-XXXXXX`) and assign this session that home. After the user logs out it would remove that directory again. The problem I ran into is the following, I need to set a home in `/etc/passwd` and I can overwrite the HOME environment variable without a problem, but applications still seem to use the home set in `passwd` instead of the environment variable, at least in a graphical environment. I can not set the home in `passwd` because I do not know about it until the session has started.

The basic logic I came up with looks like this:

- login shell started
- temporary home created
- HOME is set to this temporary home
- a real shell is forked
- after that real shell terminates, the temporary home is removed

This seems to work when I `su` into the user, but running a graphical session means that mot/all programs started use the home set in `passwd`.

Is it possible to change a user home on the fly/while a graphical session is active? DId I overlook something in the architecture of how the graphical sessions work?